# Images with rounded corners in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, rounded-corners

I have developed an rss application. I want the ListView which contains the titles and images to have the images with rounded corners. I have taken a sample code online, but the problem is that the images are still rectangular. The weird part is that I have a sliding menu, when toggled it pushes the rss ListView away, while it's being pushed the images have round corners! when they stop their pushing animation the become rectangular again. It's a pretty weird problem for me so any help?
Rounded Image class:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
{
    private float radius = 20.0f;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
    {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are u doing this?. create one rounded corner XML and set as Background to your imageview.

Comment: https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way: create `rounded_corner.xml` file into `drawable\rounded_corner.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#101010" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#808080" />

<corners android:radius="15dp" />
```

And set as `Background` to your `ImageView` like

```
android:background="@drawable\rounded_corner"
```

And also set your `RSS` image to `ImageView` as a `Src` or a `Bitmap` like:

```
 imageview.setBitmap(yourrssimage);
```

Comment: i tried it still the corners are not rounded. The weird thing is that using the code i posted the corners are round on the emulator, but on my note II they are not.

Comment: change the radius in the XML file and try. or post your all layout and code. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: ok i just noticed that some rss items dont have an image source, the default image has rounded corners, but the ones that have an image source are rectangular. I'm using setImageURI to set the image source. how can i change the uri to a bitmap to use setBitmap method?

Answer (score 0):

use rounded corner image or create xml and set as background image on imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Create one XML like below in your drawable folder.

**button_back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@color/grey">

    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#ef4444" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#992f2f" />
      <corners
          android:radius="16dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and then apply to your button like this.

```
<Button
      android:text="@string/press_me"
      android:layout_margin="12dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"

      android:background="@drawable/button_back"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stroke and list it as your imageview background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

And in your imageview xml

```
android:background="@drawable/your_stroke_xml"
```

Comment: it's working for individual images, not the images in the ListView. Plus now when I scroll up and down a white space appears on the top of the scree.

Comment: @nick28 I have similar problem. Did you found solution?

Comment: @Bresiu the class I have posted in my question works perfectly with me. The problem was with a custom ROM i was using call MIUI, I've returned to CM ROM and the class works as expected :)